# How to trigger event when double click on a tree node

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this code which creates new tab in a remote Java Class.

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem<String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem<String>> observable, TreeItem<String> oldValue, TreeItem<String> newValue)
            {
                System.out.println("Selected Text : " + newValue.getValue());
                // Create New Tab
                Tab tabdata = new Tab();
                Label tabALabel = new Label("Test");
                tabdata.setGraphic(tabALabel);

                DataStage.addNewTab(tabdata);
            }
        });
```

Can you tell me how I can modify the code to open new tab when I double click on a tree node. In my code the tab is opened when I click once. What event handler do I need?

Answer (score 12):

You can add an `EventHandler<MouseEvent>` to the `TreeView.setOnMouseClicked()` method and check for the `getClickCount()` return value of the `MouseEvent` to determine if it was a double click. Remove the `ChangeListener` above and add the logic to the `EventHandler`.

[Use the description here and apply it to your `treeView` variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950824/1625196)

It'll look something like this. You'll probably want to check the item for `null` as well.

```
treeView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {            
        if(mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2)
        {
            TreeItem<String> item = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println("Selected Text : " + item.getValue());

            // Create New Tab
            Tab tabdata = new Tab();
            Label tabALabel = new Label("Test");
            tabdata.setGraphic(tabALabel);

            DataStage.addNewTab(tabdata);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you please show me some implementation code? I'm new to JavaFX and this is something advanced for me.

Comment: What if they expand a node with another method, like the keyboard? I guess we have to bind multiple events to the same handler =/. Seems like there should be a single handler for that sort of thing. (onNodeActivated or something)

Comment: @crush This answer was specific to the double-click action. If you want to trigger something off of any expand/collapse event, then you'll want to look at the `TreeItem<T>.expandedProperty()`. You can add a `ChangeListener` to it (maybe through a `TreeCell<>` factory) and add your functionality there.  Checkout the answer here: [How to get current TreeItem reference which is expanding by user click in JavaFx 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14241151/1625196)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best practice is to implement your cell.

```
public class DoubleClickCellImpl extends TreeCell<String> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(item);
        }
    }

    public DoubleClickCellImpl() {
        super();

        setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            TreeItem<String> ti = getTreeItem();
            if (ti == null || event.getClickCount() < 2)
                return;

            // do something here.
        });
    }
}
```